# Detectar idioma del Navegador

Tags: php, localización

¿Hay una manera de detectar el idioma del navegador y realizar una acción?

 Por ejemplo que si el navegador del usuario esta en Ingles mi código realice una función como redirigir a una página o mostrar un mensaje

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma es con [locale_accept_from_http()](http://php.net/manual/es/locale.acceptfromhttp.php), para obtener la "mejor" configuración local posible y según el resultado, haces la redirección que desees:

```
$lang = locale_accept_from_http($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);

if ($lang = 'en_US') {
    header('Location: http://www.sitio.com/en');
    exit;
}

// ... otras redirecciones
```

Comment: Me parece la mejor opción. Si se pudiera hacer con un meta sería genial.

Answer (score 4):

Cuando el navegador envía información de idioma en una cabecera, llamada con `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`, tendremos un resultado parecido a esto:

```
es,en-us;q=0.3,de;q=0.1
```

Estos valores indican que el navegador acepta español `es`, inglés de EE.UU. `en-us` y alemán `de`.

Obviamente, la mayoría de los navegadores no envían tantas posibilidades, pero se obtiene la idea. La mayor parte del código que puede encontrar para determinar el idioma predeterminado simplemente busca el encabezado del primer código de idioma de 2 letras y devuelve el primero que encuentra.

Pero observando el ejemplo, notarás alguna información adicional `q=0.3` - *¿qué es eso?*

> Como parte de la especificación HTTP, estos son valores `q`, y debe ser
>   un número entre `0` y `1` (por defecto es valor `1` si no aparece ningún número).
>
> Los valores `q` proporcionan no sólo información a lo que un navegador
>   admite, sino también lo que prefiere.

En el ejemplo anterior, vemos que `es` no tiene ningún valor `q`, por lo equivale `1.0`, mientras que `en-us` es un `0.3` y `de` un `0.1`, por lo que significa que este cliente puede manejar español, inglés o alemán, pero prefiere el español si está disponible. Si no es así, el servidor puede enviar cualquiera de las otras opciones compatibles.

Ahora veremos el problema, si ignoramos el valor `q` en `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`, no tendremos la preferencias del lenguaje del cliente, si no solo el que soporta.

Si el encabezado `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` contiene varios idiomas con valores `q` diferentes, como `en, de; q = 0.9`, se le servirá el idioma principal inglés pero realmente sabe alemán, entonces tenemos que valorar el valor `q` para tener un resultado más apropiado.

Con el siguiente código y llamando la función `getDefaultLanguage()`, obtendremos el valor `q` más alto del encabezado `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`.

```
#########################################################
# Copyright © 2008 Darrin Yeager                        #
# https://www.dyeager.org/                               #
# Licensed under BSD license.                           #
#   https://www.dyeager.org/downloads/license-bsd.txt    #
#########################################################

function getDefaultLanguage() {

   if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"])) {

      return parseDefaultLanguage($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]);
   }
   else {

      return parseDefaultLanguage(NULL);
   }
}

function parseDefaultLanguage($http_accept, $deflang = "en") {

   if (isset($http_accept) && strlen($http_accept) > 1)  {

      // dividir los posibles idiomas en un array
      $x = explode(",",$http_accept);

      foreach ($x as $val) {

         // compruebe el valor q y cree un array asociativa. Si no existe el valor q, es por defecto 1
         if (preg_match("/(.*);q=([0-1]{0,1}.\d{0,4})/i",$val,$matches)) {

            $lang[$matches[1]] = (float)$matches[2];
         } 
         else {

            $lang[$val] = 1.0;
         }
      }

      // retornamos el idioma por defecto el cual es el valor q más alto
      $qval = 0.0;

      foreach ($lang as $key => $value) {

         if ($value > $qval) {

            $qval = (float)$value;
            $deflang = $key;
         }
      }
   }

   return strtolower($deflang);
}
```

- Fuente original: [getting-browser-default-language-php](https://www.dyeager.org/2008/10/getting-browser-default-language-php.html)
- [Especificación "Accept-Language" (q-value) w3.org](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) (Inglés)

Comment: +1 Por ser la respuesta mas completa en cuanto al valor de `$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]` y significado del mismo.

Answer (score 2):

Teniendo en cuenta que quizá no tengas traducción **para todos los idiomas**, podrías proceder de un modo como este.

El `default` del bloque `switch` te llevará o incluirá la página que desees en caso de no detectar nada o de detectar una lengua para la cual no tienes traducción, como podría ser el islandés, el danés, el ruso...

```
<?php
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
switch ($lang){
    case "es":
        //echo "PAGE ES";
        include("index_es.php");//puede ser header(Location...) u otra cosa
        break;
    case "fr":
        //echo "PAGE FR";
        include("index_fr.php");//puede ser header(Location...) u otra cosa
        break;
    case "it":
        //echo "PAGE IT";
        include("index_it.php");
        break;
    case "en":
        //echo "PAGE EN";
        include("index_en.php");
        break;        
    default:
        //echo "PAGE EN - Configuración por defecto";
        include("index_en.php");//incluye página en inglés, o en otro idioma, si se detecta otro tipo de lengua no indicada en los case
        break;
}
?>
```

Además, si tenemos en cuenta [esta nota del Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/locale.acceptfromhttp.php#110350):

> It's good to mention that if user browser will not send
>   `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`, the output from:
>
> ```
> Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
> ```
>
> Will be null.
>
> So remember to set up a fail over scenario!

el código de más arriba usaría la página por defecto en caso de no encontrar información sobre el idioma.

---

Fuente: [Detect Browser Language in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3770616/5587982)

Comment: Me parece una buena respuesta, pero podrías traducir la cita en español ?

Comment: el último `case: "en"` se puede ahorrar ya que se pone por `default`